# Maven is trying to dow

Tags: grails, maven, build, jersey

Build fails with message:

"Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.0.3:maven-clean (default) on project primeplace: Failed to create classpath for Grails execution. Encountered problems resolving dependencies of the executable in preparation for its execution. Failure to find com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:bundle:1.11 in http: //myrepro/nexus/content/groups/public
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of places-nexus-public has elapsed or updates are forced"

My pom.xml contains the following about Jersey:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth-signature</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: http: //myrepro/nexus/content/groups/public there is a space between the http: and // Is this error pasted properly into the question or do you need to check the local repository URL and remove that space perhaps?

Comment: the space was added by me in purpose

Answer (score 0):

Just delete you local repository under ${HOME}/.m2/repository and retry your build. If it fails an other time you might need to change the [dependencies you given](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.sun.jersey|jersey-client|1.11|bundle).
It might be necessary to change the dependency into the following (for the first dependency)

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
      <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
```